# How to convert python list to Pandas series

Tags: python, pandas

I have a python list l.The first few elements of the list looks like below

```
[751883787]
[751026090]
[752575831]
[751031278]
[751032392]
[751027358]
[751052118]
```

I want to convert this list to pandas.core.series.Series with 2 leading 0.My final outcome will look like

```
00751883787
00751026090
00752575831
00751031278
00751032392
00751027358
00751052118
```

I'm working in Python 3.x in windows environment.Can you suggest me how to do this?
Also my list contains around 2000000 elements

Answer (score 8):

you can try:

```
list=[121,123,125,145]
series='00'+pd.Series(list).astype(str)
print(series)
```

output:

```
0    00121
1    00123
2    00125
3    00145
dtype: object
```

Comment: @riccardo.Thanks a lot it works. But sorry my current reputation doesn't allow me select that the answer is useful or correct

Answer (score 4):

First use `DataFrame` constructor with columns, then cast to `string` and last add `0` by [`Series.str.zfill`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.zfill.html) if nested `list`s:

```
lst = [[751883787],
       [751026090],
       [752575831],
       [751031278],
       [751032392],
       [751027358],
       [751052118]]

s = pd.DataFrame(lst, columns=['a'])['a'].astype(str).str.zfill(11)
print (s)
0    00751883787
1    00751026090
2    00752575831
3    00751031278
4    00751032392
5    00751027358
6    00751052118
Name: a, dtype: object
```

---

If there is one `list` only:

```
lst = [751883787,
       751026090,
       752575831,
       751031278,
       751032392,
       751027358,
       751052118]


s = pd.Series(lst).astype(str).str.zfill(11)
print (s)
0    00751883787
1    00751026090
2    00752575831
3    00751031278
4    00751032392
5    00751027358
6    00751052118
dtype: object
```

Comment: I performed almost identical operations but using list comprehension, but `pandas` method seems ~3x slower. I thought `.astype(str).str.zfill(11)` would all be vectorised? Do you have an idea about why? [Benchmarking results in my post]

Comment: It is expected output, because pandas `str` function handle `NaN`s, so are slowier.

Comment: I see, maybe there should be an `na=False` parameter for `astype` !

Comment: there is no such parameter

Answer (score 2):

This is one way.

```
from itertools import chain; concat = chain.from_iterable
import pandas as pd

lst = [[751883787],
       [751026090],
       [752575831],
       [751031278]]

pd.DataFrame({'a': pd.Series([str(i).zfill(11) for i in concat(lst)])})

             a
0  00751883787
1  00751026090
2  00752575831
3  00751031278
```

Some benchmarking, relevant since your dataframe is large:

```
from itertools import chain; concat = chain.from_iterable
import pandas as pd

lst = [[751883787],
       [751026090],
       [752575831],
       [751031278],
       [751032392],
       [751027358],
       [751052118]]*300000

%timeit pd.DataFrame(lst, columns=['a'])['a'].astype(str).str.zfill(11)
# 1 loop, best of 3: 7.88 s per loop

%timeit pd.DataFrame({'a': pd.Series([str(i).zfill(11) for i in concat(lst)])})
# 1 loop, best of 3: 2.06 s per loop
```

Answer (score 1):

both the given answers are usefull ... below is the summrise one

```
import pandas as pd
mylist = [751883787,751026090,752575831,751031278]
mysers = pd.Series(mylist).astype(str).str.zfill(11)
print (mysers)

./test
0    00751883787
1    00751026090
2    00752575831
3    00751031278
dtype: object
```

another way around is , cast the dtype of the series to str using astype and use vectorised str.zfill to pad with 00, though using lamda will be more easy to read ..

```
import pandas as pd
mylist = pd.DataFrame([751883787,751026090,752575831,751031278], columns=['coln'])
result = mylist.coln.apply(lambda x: str(int(x)).zfill(11))
print(result)
```

Below is the result..

```
./test
0    00751883787
1    00751026090
2    00752575831
3    00751031278
Name: coln, dtype: object
```

Comment: And for second apprach is important no `NaN`s, else failed ;)

Comment: @jezrael, i couldn't get you sorry :(

Comment: If `NaN`s values in list then second solution failed.

Comment: `mylist = [751883787,751026090,752575831,751031278, np.nan]`

Comment: @jezrael you are correct ... i just applied it for the example quoted

Comment: Yes, I want only pointed why in pandas is better use `str.` functions, not `lambda` ;)

Comment: You beated me @jezrael ;) thats why in my opening ans i said given solution are useful !